# How to Count Unique Arrays in a Multidimensional Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am looking for a way to not only find unique arrays within a multidimensional array, but also count how many times a particular array occurs.

For Example

```
var arr = [[1,2], [1,2], [1,3], [1,4], [1,4], [1,4]]; 
var uniqueArrays = []; 
var theCount = [];

// Code 

???

// Results
uniqueArrays === [[1,2], [1,3], [1,4]]
theCount ==== [2, 1, 3]
```

Edit:
I didn't realize that I had to show my attempts of how I should solve a problem before I asked a question.

I do know how to count the length of an array use the length() method. I do know how to filter unique arrays from a multi-dimensional array. I did not post my attempts using those tools though because those two issues have been solved to death.

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. Stack Overflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: I think it's pretty clear what I am looking for as it was solved below almost immediately after I posted it. I didn't post my attempts, because the primary issue that I had was not understanding how to tackle the issue. If I would have posted the numerous for loops, functions, etc that I tried it would not have made anything more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can map each inner array to a stringified version of itself using `.map(JSON.stringified)`. Now, using this new array, you can reduce it to an object which contains each stringified array as a key, and keeps the number of occurrences as its value. While reducing, you can check whether or not the object's key has already been set using `a[k] = (a[k] || 0)+1`. If it has already been set, it will use the current number stored at the key and increment it by 1, if it hasn't already been set it will set it equal to zero, and then increment it by 1 (which acts as the default value for any new keys (i.e newly seen arrays)).

Lastly, you can get the keys from your object which represent each unique array as strings using `Object.keys()`, and parse each back into a non-stringified array using `JSON.parse`. You can get the counts from your array by using `Object.values()` as this will get all the values (ie: the counters) of your reduced object and put them into an array.

See example below:

```js
const arr = [[1,2], [1,2], [1,3], [1,4], [1,4], [1,4]]; 

const arr_str = arr.map(JSON.stringify);
const arr_map = arr_str.reduce((a, k) => (a[k] = (a[k] || 0) + 1, a), {});
const uniqueArrays = Array.from(Object.keys(arr_map), JSON.parse);
const theCount = Object.values(arr_map);

console.log(uniqueArrays);
console.log(theCount);
```

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate the explanation as well.

Answer (score 1):

you can use below code

```js
var arr = [[1,2], [1,2], [1,3], [1,4], [1,4], [1,4]]; 
var uniqueArrays = []; 
var theCount = [];
var test = [], obj ={};
arr.forEach(val => {
    if(test.indexOf(val.toString()) == -1){
        test.push(val.toString());
        obj[val.toString()] = 1;
        uniqueArrays.push(val);
    }else{
        obj[val.toString()] += 1;

    }

})
theCount = Object.values(obj);
console.log(uniqueArrays);
console.log(theCount);
```

Hope it will help you.